# Submit button outside the <form> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been searching for two hours and I couldn't find any solutions.

I would like to have two submit buttons, one inside the < form > tag and one outside the < form > tag.

```
<form id="example" name="example" action="post">
    Input <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<div class="button">Submit</div>
```

JS / jQuery

```
$(".button").click( function() {
    alert("Button clicked");
});
```

How can I send the form with the ('.button') class outside the form ?

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQLXb/

Comment: I tried both $('#example').trigger('submit'); and $('#example').submit(); but it doesn't want to work for me! Can someone please post me the correct JS Fiddle ?

Answer (score 16):

Use the `submit()` function to trigger the form submission:

```
$(".button").click( function() {
    $('#example').submit();
});
```

You can also use the `trigger()` function:

```
$(".button").click( function() {
    $('#example').trigger('submit');
});
```

Although they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I tried both, but doesn't want to work. This is my new Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jWuAe/

Comment: I don't think you can submit a `<form>` in jsfiddle, it will work in a real document though.

Answer (score 3):

use [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to submit the form

```
$(".button").click( function() {
   $('#example').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could trigger the `submit` event on the form:

```
$('#example').trigger('submit')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").click( function() {
    $('#example').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").bind("click",function() {
    $('#example').submit();
});
```